# Please suggest the learning material for C++ and python in context to ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need a time effective (the tutorial which let me learn the basic concepts easily with time effective way) tutorial that can let me learn C++ and python in context to programming in ROS.
Please suggest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68482/please-suggest-the-learning-material-for-c++-and-python-in-context-to-ros?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I, personnally, found those ressources helpful (but I already had some programming skills) :

- [http://www.cs.mun.ca/~av/courses/ar/?page_id=36](http://www.cs.mun.ca/%7Eav/courses/ar/?page_id=36) (no correction but it is a nice exercise to do to better understand how things work)
- https://www.cs.hmc.edu/twiki/bin/view/Robotics/SummerStartPage2012 (exercises on Turtlebot 1, still no correction)

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-23**:
I think these links are helpful as I do have some programming skill. Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would be surprised if a ROS-specific tutorial existed for learning the very basic concepts of C++ or Python. The simplest system in ROS consists of running roscore, a publisher and a subscriber (as described in the [first tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber)). This won't make much sense until you know enough of a language to write functions and comfortably manipulate data. So, If you haven't programmed before, work your way through **several** different Python tutorials, until you're comfortable with basic data structures, flow control, writing functions, and classes. ([google's](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) looks reasonably concise, but may not cover enough). Skip C++ until you have your robot moving around.

However, ROS *is* great for learning how to design robotic systems. Bill Smart teaches an introduction to robotics course using ROS and turtlebots. His [course materials](http://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse550/) are online, and might be of interest to you.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-24**:
I gone through the content of the Bill's course material I hope I will be able to utilize it most.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the Python side of things, I recently needed to come up to speed pretty quickly with the Python syntax to better be able to make out the ROS examples in the language.  I found a bunch of Python tutorials on YouTube, but I settled on the videos of the 2-day Python class given by Nick Parlante at Google for their employees:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk

It takes about 5 hours to sit through all the videos, but Nick is pretty good instructor and the class moves a long at a pretty good clip so you won't get bored if you are already generally familiar with basic programming concepts.

This class won't teach you everything about Python, but for the things that you didn't learn you be well prepared to then pick up the missing pieces from many of the Python programming books.

---

Originally posted by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) with karma: 153 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thanks, It will definitely be good for me to start with it.